# WordPress Media Library is invisible

Tags: image, wordpress

I'm encountering a really frustrating problem with WordPress and I hope someone can help. Images are uploading to WordPress correctly (they are in the library) but once a file is uploaded there is simply a blank screen.  Closing and reopening the "Add an Image" window, I still cannot add them to posts unless I enter the full URL because the "Media Library" tab simply doesn't show anything (see below - interface shows there are 33 images and 4 tabbed pages, but none of them are displayed.

I've about reached the end of my rope trying to fix this problem.  Searched and searched and can find no answer.  Some people had similar problems, and I tried all of their posted solutions, including:

- Uninstalled all plugins
- Nuked and reinstalled all wordpress files
- Checked browser versions (occurring in Chrome 7.0.5 and FireFox 3.2)
- No JavaScript errors found (used Firebug and Chrome's JS panel)
- Checked domain name in Settings for improper capitalization
- Checked image URL to make sure there was no gibberish, and there isn't

Does anyone have any suggestions (I'm running version 3.0.2 on Apache)?  I'd be forever in your debt.  Thank you!

> Oops, it won't let me post an image because of 'spam protection.'  Drats!

Answer (score 0):

Check this: [WordPress › Support » Image/Media Uploader problems?](https://timbdesign.com/25-image-media-uploader-problems-wordpress)

Who is your web host? How much php memory are you allocated? Is GD library for php installed?

Comment: My web host is my university.  The PHP function memory_get_peak_usage  tells me I have 59880, and GD library is installed.

Comment: php safe mode on? url access? Do you have a php.ini file in your account? Sounds like a global php setting that the U has set for security. Can't blame them for that.